# Prevent submenu from being clipped by overflow scrollable container

Tags: jquery, html, css

With the following markup, I want to be able to have the dropdown menu not be clipped by the scrollable div container when the menu is shown for a table row item near the bottom of the container.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100px; width: auto;">
    <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>                 
              <ul class="submenu"><li>option</li></ul>
            </li> 
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to prevent the dropdown menu from being clipped by the scrollable div container?

jFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hextL6zx/1/

Comment: Create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Adjust the hight of the container?

Comment: Change the z-index of the drop down to be a higher value than the container

Comment: @Sleek Geek Added a fiddle per your request.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned in the comments, z-index will help accomplish what you're looking for. Perhaps this fiddle will help:

```
 .dropdown {
    z-index: 100;
 }
```

Comment: Please see the fiddle I added in my question.

Comment: That solution works until you scroll and then the dropdown menu is placed well below the container.

Comment: After a bit of searching I found this example, perhaps it will help:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5JvA/